# How can I access the plain text loaded in an <iframe> on IE?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` whose `src` points to a plain text file (not HTML). The text gets loaded and displayed on screen, but seems to be hidden to JavaScript.

In other browsers, `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerText` is enough to get it for you, but IE returns an empty string in that case.

Is there a way that IE can access the text inside the file without involving a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this file using XmlHttpRequest. If the browser can read it, so can XmlHttpRequest.

```
/* Read a file  using xmlhttprequest 

If the HTML file with your javascript app has been saved to disk, 
this is an easy way to read in a data file.  Writing out is 
more complicated and requires either an ActiveX object (IE) 
or XPCOM (Mozilla).

fname - relative path to the file
callback - function to call with file text
*/
function readFileHttp(fname, callback) {
   xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { 
          callback(xmlhttp.responseText); 
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", fname, true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
}

/*
Return a cross-browser xmlhttp request object
*/
function getXmlHttp() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   if (xmlhttp == null) {
      alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
   }
   return xmlhttp;
}
```

Call the `readFileHttp(fname, callback)` using the `iframe.src` property for the `fname` parameter.
The callback parameter should be a function that does whatever you want with the result.

Something like this:

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframeIdGoesHere');
readFileHttp(myIFrame.src, function(result){
    //process the result
});
```

Comment: If you would be using jquery it would be a lot easier using the jQuery.get() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method. The principle is the same though.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT based on comment and edit in question:

It might be that `body` is not available as a js property on the document. You could try:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText
```

- *<sub>**My original answer** (kept only as reference because of the comment):</sub>*

  > <sup>You
  >   say in a comment that you pull the
  >   path from an `<input type='file' />`.
  >   You can use that to upload the file to
  >   the server, and then read it using
  >   simple file reading mechanisms. (after
  >   all, the `<input type='file' />` is
  >   meant for server uploads...)</sup>

Comment: The question is specifically about a JavaScript solution; there is no server in this application. I updated the wording to be a bit more explicit about this.

Comment: This works as a pure JS solution, thanks.  Trying to keep things as lean as possible, not doing much work in JS either, so I don't want to load umpteen libraries to do something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried the `innerHTML` property?

Alternatively, the more "proper" way to do this is to request the file directly with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Yes, I tried innerText and it's also an empty string. And I'd use XMLHttpRequest, but I'm actually accessing a local file (whose path is pulled out of a <input type='file' />), so security measures prevent that. Other browsers have the FileAPI or whatnot to handle this, but IE does not.

Answer (score 0):

and

`window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML`

?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: no, this was a simple question-answer to the question "Is there a way that IE can access the text inside the file without involving a server?"